# P5.JS a box of text smoothly floating/hovering randomly in an area

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I would like to have a box/card with text in it. Then i would like that box/card to float/hover randomly and smoothly around an area.  I have tried to use the P5.js random function but it is too jittery and has no smoothness to it. I am still a very much beginner with P5.JS and do not understand how to approach this. Do i just select a div element with the card and then apply some motion to it?

Comment: Hi, show us the code you wrote that was too jiterry!